# Create a "Building Queue" with rails associated to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, delayed-job, job-scheduling

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails and to do so I am developing a web game.

This game is in the same genre as Travian, the players can build buildings etc...

I'm a bit stuck on this feature to implement my "building queue", I explain.

A player put in his queue at most 3 buildings.
When the first one is finished, we check first if he has the necessary resources to go to the next one and so on.

Currently, I manage my queue with a BuildQueue table. As long as the previous build is not finished we wait. Once the build is launched, it starts a thread that sleeps for the duration of the build :

```
build_in_progress = BuildQueue.where(queue_type: 'build', kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id)

# It means that the building queue is empty
if build_in_progress.empty?

  build_time = time(building)
  new_queue = BuildQueue.create(queue_type: 'build', build: building, kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id, build_time: build_time)

  Thread.start do
    sleep build_time

    # [...] Here I update the building concerned
    new_queue.destroy
  end
else
  build_in_progress_id = build_in_progress.last.id
  new_queue = BuildQueue.create(queue_type: 'build', build: building, kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id)

  Thread.start do
    build_in_progress = BuildQueue.find_by_id(build_in_progress_id)
    until build_in_progress.nil?
      sleep 1
      build_in_progress = BuildQueue.find_by_id(build_in_progress_id)
    end

    # We check that the player still has the necessary resources
    cost = cost(building)

    if can_upgrade?(cost)
      build_time = time(building)
      new_queue.build_time = build_time
      new_queue.save

      sleep build_time

      # [...] Here I update the building concerned
      Notification.create(kingdom_id: current_kingdom.id, notif_type: 'build', message: "The construction of #{t("buildings.#{building}")} is finished", icon: 'gavel')
    end

    new_queue.destroy
  end
end
```

So it's a rudimentary system but it works.

I would like to improve it but I have trouble finding a way to do that.

I found the use of Rails jobs with ActiveJob but I don't know if it is possible to :

- link a job to a user and that each launched job waits until the previous one is finished?
- And if job 2 can't start, try immediately to start job 3

I also saw the possibility to use Redis and place my jobs in the order they should be finished. But here I have the same problem

- If job 2 can't be launched because the player doesn't have the resources, you have to immediately try to launch job 3

Otherwise as a last resort I thought of a cron system but I think it's even worse than what I'm doing now

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [gem Wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper). It also has various adapters for asynchronous event handling.

Comment: I'm not sure if it solves my problem, but I still have to use my BuildQueue table, don't I? So the gem just allows me to avoid using a thread?

Comment: You can do without a gem. As far as I understand the task, here you need to use callbacks to call the method for the construction of the next building. We need to create objects that can send and process these callbacks. Buildings must be done asynchronously, for example, via sidekiq

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it
Do you have more details to give me? :D thank you